Failed To Start Kotlin

In sublime text I installed lsp-kotlin but got the error shown in the picture above. I need help to solve this problem
I tried installing kotlin-language-server but that did not work.
I also set up environment variable path but that also did not work.

Don't post images to show error messages.  Here's is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Welcome. https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP/issues/1644. Did you update it?

In NetBeans org.netbeans.modules.lsp.client is installable as well.
